# Docker-Compose for windows not recognizing the env_file variable in in the docker-compose.yml file

Tags: windows, environment-variables, docker

I'm trying to solve a problem here : I have docker for windows installation with a `docker-compose.yml` file. I'm trying to set the environment variable to `test.env` rather than `.env`.

The error I get, no matter what I try, is this:

```
D:\apps\repos\js-docker>docker-compose build
ERROR: Couldn't find env file: D:\apps\repos\js-docker\.env
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file is below:

```
# Copyright (c) 2016. TIBCO Software Inc.
# This file is subject to the license terms contained
# in the license file that is distributed with this file.
# version: 6.3.0-v1.0.4

version: '2'

# network used by both JasperReports Server and PostgreSQL containers
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "192.168.5.1/24"

services:
  jasperserver:
    env_file:
     - test.env
    build: .

    # expose port 8080 and bind it to 8080 on host
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
    # set depends on js_database service
    depends_on:
      - js_database
    # point to env file with key=value entries 

    #env_file:
    # - test.env


    # setting following values here will override settings from env_file
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=js_database
    volumes:
      - jrs_webapp:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver-pro
      - jrs_license:/usr/local/share/jasperreports-pro/license 
      - jrs_customization:/usr/local/share/jasperreports-pro/customization
      # a test to map the licensing file in docker compose 
      # Chris Gauthier June 04, 2019
      - /C/Users/chris/Documents/resources/license:/usr/local/share/jasperreports-pro/license
      #/C/Users/chris/Documents/resources/license:/usr/src/jasperreports-server/
      # for a mac
      #- /Users/chris/resources/license:/usr/local/share/jasperreports-pro/license
      #- /C/Users/chris/Documents/resources/license:/usr/src/jasperreports-server
      # for Mac OS you may want to define local path for volume mounts. 
      # Note that defining path for a named volume is not supported 
      # by Compose. For example:
      # - /some-local-path:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver-pro
      # - ~/jasperreports-pro/license:/usr/local/share/jasperreports-pro/license
      # - /tmp/customization:/usr/local/share/jasperreports-pro/customization
  js_database:
    image: postgres:9.4
    env_file: .env

volumes:
  jrs_webapp:
    driver: local
  jrs_license:
  jrs_customization:
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see both in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
jasperserver:
  env_file:
   - test.env
```

And :

```
js_database:
  image: postgres:9.4
  env_file: .env
```

Perhaps you should also set the second one to `test.env`.